# iOS Screen Time API not working on test flight

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I've created an iOS app using Flutter and using the Screen Time API for restricting apps with a countdown as a trigger. It's working on the simulator and on my connected iPad device. But when I uploaded it to TestFlight, it doesn't work properly. The scenario is:

1. Set app countdown to 20 seconds
2. Select YouTube app that will be restricted after the countdown ends
3. Start the countdown
4. Open the YouTube app
5. After 20 seconds, the YouTube app is restricted automatically even if it is still in use.

This scenario is working fine on my simulator and my debugging iPad. But in the TestFlight, YouTube is not restricted when the countdown ends. And if the user did not open YouTube when the countdown ended, it can be restricted. Does anyone know why?